# How to remove ASP.NET error message for security audit

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

As soon as I introduce script in developer tool's console window an asp.net error message appeared

Script:

```
for(var i = 0;i < 5;i++)
{
    document.cookie = i+"="+"a".repeat(4000)
};
frame=document.createElement("iframe");
frame.src ="/";
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

Error message:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

[image]

I want to display a non-ASP.NET message (as shown below) rather than this ASP.NET system error message.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to create a customized page using either of these two methods after setting up the ASPX error page.

1- n the Web.config file, define custom error handling to route specific HTTP error codes to your custom error page

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404Page.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2- Implement global error handling by handling errors in the Application_Error event within the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
}
```